# Deserializing QByteArray with known QMetaType::Type into QVariant

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QByteArray` containing the raw data of a variable.
The `QMetaType::Type` describing the variable is known.

I want to deserialize this variable into a `QVariant`

With the following inputs :

```cpp
QByteArray bytes; // Consider it initialized
QMetaType::Type type; // Same
```

My attempts so far do not work:

```cpp
QVariant var{bytes};
var.convert(type); // Does not work, apparently QVariant expects bytes to be a string representation of the variable
```

```cpp
QDataStream ds(bytes, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QVariant var;
ds >> var; // Does not work because bytes does not come from the serialization of a QVariant (especially, it lacks type information)
```

I cannot change my inputs or output types :

- The inputs *must* be of type `QByteArray` and `QMetaType::Type`.
- The output *must* be of type `QVariant`

Example :

```cpp
//Inputs
QByteArray bytes = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 };
QMetaType::Type type = QMetaType::UInt; // Suppose the size of unsigned int is 4 bytes (could be 2)
// Note: this is an example, in pratice I have to manage many types, including double

//Expected output:
QVariant var = deserialize(bytes, type);
// var.type() == QMetaType::UInt
// var.toUInt() == 305419896 (== 0x12345678)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do this: `auto v = QVariant(bytes.toUInt());`?

Comment: Because `unsigned int` won't be the only type I will receive, this was just an example. I'd like to avoid managing each type separately.

Comment: Did you find a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem, I got around constructing the `QVariant` from a `QByteArray` directly through its `data()` method using the provided type id:

```
QByteArray bytes; // Consider it initialized
QMetaType::Type type; // Same
QVariant result(type.id(),bytes.data());
```

If the construction fails, you will end up with an invalid `QVariant`, but so far, for my types, it worked well.

Answer (score -1):

You can write to an `unsigned int` and then convert it to `QVariant`:

```
    const char data[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 };
    QByteArray bytes { QByteArray::fromRawData( data, 4) };

    QDataStream s {&bytes, QIODevice::ReadOnly};
    //write out the data to uint
    unsigned int x{};
    s >> x;

    //create a Qvariant from it
    QVariant var{x};

    qDebug () << "x: " << x;                       //305419896
    qDebug () << "variant: " << var;               //QVariant(uint, 305419896)
    qDebug () << "variant uint: " << var.toUInt(); //305419896
```

Alternatively you can also directly construct a `QVariant`:

```
    auto v = QVariant(bytes.toHex().toUInt());
    //auto v = QVariant(bytes.toUInt());            //this will not work
    qDebug () << "Bytes to uint; " << v.toUInt(); //305419896
```

Comment: I would prefer avoiding converting to the real type then to `QVariant`. In practice I will receive many inputs with many different types. Having to manage each of the types would be tedious. Will using `toHex()` work for any type ?

Comment: `QByteArray` contains rawbytes, so yes,  `toHex()` will always work

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, sorry, I meant, will I be able to convert to any type from the result of `toHex()`?

Comment: You can convert to `any` type from `QByteArray` if you want. So yes, but you will have to do the serialization yourself if the TYPE is a user defined type and not simple int, short, long etc.